# When is $f(X)$ convex?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space, and let $f: X \to X$ be a nonlinear operator, $\mathrm{Dom}(f)=X$.

When is $f(X)$ convex?

Comment: Sometimes it is. What can you expect, without any further assumption on $f$?

Comment: I think that the best thing which can be said here is: $f(X)$ is convex when given $x,y\in X$, $tf(x)+(1-t)f(y)\in f(X)$ for $t\in [0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

As Tomás said: $f(X)$ is convex if and only if the following holds:

> for every $x,y\in X$ and every $t\in (0,1)$ there exists $z\in X$ such that $$f(z) = tf(x)+(1-t)f(y)$$